# Looking for a general academic term on "technology trees" and related research and not sure where to ask best

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm not sure whether this question is well on topic at History of Science and Mathematics?

My question:

> From computer games like Civilizations, we know the concept of the
> [technology tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_tree), i.e. different technologies and innovations are
> conceived to be interlinked in a graph.
>
> Is there actually such a thing (maybe not exactly but comparable) in reality* in terms of research and technology management and also historical analysis and if yes what is the
> proper term for that (given that the "TechTree" term is specific to games?)

* Besides the paper citation graph